# What does CXF stands for in "Apache CXF"?

Tags: java, cxf, acronym

What does `CXF` abbreviation mean?

What is "**C**" ?

What is "**X**" ?

What is "**F**" ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

According to <s>this</s> (edit: link content is no longer available) it's the combination of two projects (Celtix and XFire) and the name comes from the initial letters of each project.

Comment: Its interesting that there is no correlation between names - CXF and JAX-RS(the specification CXF implements).

Comment: Link is not broken, but the content is not there anymore

Answer (score 17):

`Apache CXF` is the product of two projects, `Celtix` and `XFire`, hence the name `CXF`.

`Celtix`, an open source Java-based `Enterprise Service Bus` (ESB) project, is a product of ObjectWeb consortia that delivers open source middleware solutions. The project was sponsored by `IONA`.

On the other hand, `XFire`, a Java-based `SOAP` framework, is an open source project from `Codehaus`. Both `Celtix` and `XFire`, while in their initial versions, had many things in common and therefore the developers of both projects decided to bring out the best of both worlds and planned a better 2.0 version of `Celtix` and `XFire`.

The communities of both these projects entered incubation at the Apache Software foundation to develop version 2.0.  It took about 20 months at the Apache incubator before CXF finally rolled out.

`CXF` is now formally known as `Apache CXF` which concentrates on delivering an open source web service framework. The framework which had its first release as `v2.0`, is now evolved as `v2.2`, with bug fixes, and the addition of new features.